# Why the icon don't show in SmartGWT TreeGrid?

Tags: icons, smartgwt, treegrid

all

i have set up an TreeGrid ,i set up an romote datasource for it.

In the callback founction,i use setData(include the icon information) for the TreeGrid instance,so TreeGrid instance have the icon value in it.

but show the default icon.what's the problem?!

PS:
1 have set setCustomIconProperty("icon"); for TreeGrid;
2 TreeGrid.redraw() don't wrok.

thank you
july

Comment: A little bit of code will be welcome

Comment: Sorry,As you see,these code are in different files,so it's hard to post code.the key is:my treeGrid don't show icon,for it use a remote datasource! thank you for response.